# Conjugate of unit quaternion

Tags: rotations, quaternions

In the context of using unit quaternions to represent 3D rotations, I'm aware that the inverse is the conjugate.

So if I have a unit quaternion Q = {qw, qx, qy, qz} (where qw is the scalar part), the conjugate Q' = {qw, -qx, -qy, -qz}.

Can't I simply use Q' = {-qw, qx, qy, qz} as the conjugate instead? Isn't it identical?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: What makes you think it's identical? Your definition has a $-1$ multiplying it, so if we multiplied it together according to your definition we'd end up with $QQ' = -1$.

Comment: Plus we want the case $q_y=q_z=0$ to recover how complex numbers work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about quaternions and rotations, $$q=\left(\cos\frac\theta 2,\sin\frac\theta 2 e_x,\sin\frac\theta 2 e_y,\sin\frac\theta 2 e_z\right)$$
Here $(e_x,e_y,e_z)$ represents the rotation axis. An inverse rotation can be obtained by either switching $(e_x,e_y,e_z)$ to $(-e_x,-e_y,-e_z)$, or switching $\theta$ to $-\theta$. Both have the effect of $$q^*=q^{-1}=\left(\cos\frac\theta 2,-\sin\frac\theta 2 e_x,-\sin\frac\theta 2 e_y,-\sin\frac\theta 2 e_z\right)$$